# Recording (counting) Method calls in C# /VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, methods, profiling

Currently I'm developing a C# DLL to be used in a native C++ Application. Since the initialization of my DLL is rather slow I'd like to do some analysis there. Basically I would like to know which methods in my DLL are called in which order and how often.

One way would be to step through the code with the debugger. But that would take ages ;-) I'd rather have some kind of list that shows which of my methods was called how often.

Is there any way to get this automatically (without altering my code)?
Maybe even without third party tools like profilers etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If don't want to alter your code or make a manual expection with a debugger, a profiler is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a tip for how to quickly count method calls in recent versions of Visual Studio without changing and compiling code or using a profiler:

- Add a breakpoint in the target method
- Right-click the breakpoint and select the "Actions" menu item
- In "Actions" -> "Log a message to Output Window:" type your method name
- Run the code
- Copy the program output to Notepad++
- In the Noptepad++ "Find" window use the "Count" button to count the number of calls of the method name

Answer (score 2):

In the **Analyze** menu in Visual Studio 2010 you have the **Launch Performance Wizard** (I don't know the edition that is required for this). That should enable you to get a good idea what part of your code is taking so much time to execute.